# Internet Explorer 8 partially displaying my webpage

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, cgi

Hi I have written a Perl cgi script that prints a calendar. It works fine in IE10, Firefox and Chrome but not in IE8 and also not in IE Tab+ pulgin of Firefox. The page is displayed partially and the rest is clipped off... 
The webpage also has embedded Javascript in it.

Has anyone faced this problem before? Any solutions??

I can't put the screen shots but I can say that I have 5 columns in my table, two and half columns are displayed, the java script attached to those cells work but the rest 2 and half columns are missing.

*this may not be pretty but this reproduces the problem.

*I tried this example in jsfiddle, there i saw that the two columns were overlapping over one other.

```
<html>
<style>
#today
{
    color:red;
}
table
{
 table-layout: fixed;
 text-align:center;
width: 800px;
height: 500px;
}

td
{
    padding : 0px 0px; 
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
    text-align:center; 
    font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
<body bgcolor="#COCOCO">
<h1>my blah blah blah Calendar</h1>
<table>
 <t><td> 
<table color="black" bgcolor="white" border="1px">
<tr>
xfgvfsd
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Su</td>
<td>Mo</td>
<td>Tu</td>
<td>We</td>
<td>Th</td>
<td>Fr</td>
<td>Sa</td>
</tr>

</table>
 </td> 
 <td colsize="5">

edsafsdg
 </td></tr> 
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to provide code for someone to help you. Try creating an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that demonstrates the problem. Surely someone can help you then.

Comment: Make sure IE8 isn't running in quirks mode: Open the developer console using F12 and check the browser mode. Add a `<!DOCTYPE html>` to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your document does not have a doctype or has blank space before the doctype, it will render in compatibility or quirks mode. This will cause the browser to use an older rendering engine with all the weird layout bugs included.

To verify this, press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open your MSIE Developer Console and check the browser rendering mode.

If IE is rendering in quirks mode, you should add a doctype like `<!DOCTYPE html>` immediately before the `<html>` tag to ensure that it isn't triggered automatically.

You should also add a meta tag to your `<head>` to force IE to render the page with the latest rendering engine:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This should prevent IE from using compatibility mode. There are other server-side steps you can take as well. Take a look at this [MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx) for all the specific details.

Comment: Hi your tip was helpful, i saw that the webpage was being displayed in IE7 mode not IE8 and it displayed correctly when i manually selected IE8 mode. But adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` did not help and it still is being displayed in IE7 mode.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more information. It sounds like your problem is compatibility mode, which can usually be fixed with a meta tag.